# Jquery/Javascript to allow a specific webpage in a specific time of the day in the week

Tags: javascript

Is there a Jquery/Javascript to allow a specific webpage to be access only in a specific time of the day in the week? for example: in a course you want your students to access your webpage in your network in a certain hour of the day and the week!!!

Comment: thanks for the quick response guys... but I should mentioned that i want the specific content on the a specific webpage on the intranet to be visible on a specific time of the day on the week days

Answer (score 2):

No: JavaScript (and jQuery, which is just a library implemented in JavaScript) runs in the browser, on the page that **has been delivered to the user**. You could 'hide' the page after it gets delivered using JS, but once you send the page it is in their hands; they can choose to unhide and interact with it however they want.

It is up the web server software (e.g. IIS, Apache, Nginx) to decide whether or not to serve a page. For example, the [mod_sequester](http://meepzor.com/packages/mod_sequester/mod_sequester.html) module for Apache lets you control serving of content based on date/time ranges. Or, you could use Apache to [send different content based on time of day](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/advanced.html#time-dependent).

Alternatively, it is up to any dynamic application you have (e.g. Ruby on Rails, PHP) to decide to change the contents of the page sent to the browser based on arbitrary criteria. Any custom logic will do here.

Comment: thanks for hand... I wish this server was in apache!!! but this is a IIS6 asp intranet webpage.

Comment: @bigwelly Then see: http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2010/04/05/time-dependent-url-rewriting.aspx  Note that if this answer has solved your question, you should ["accept it"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

I would not do that through JavaScript, because it is a client sided script. Very easy to view source and get the page. So, restricting access schould be done on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to do that on the server side, only serving the page on a specific day of the week.  JavaScript can modify the delivered page's content depending on the day of the week, but if the client has javascript disabled then the page will come right through anyway.